# how to repaint QListWidget after changing caption of QListZWidget Item

Tags: qt, qt4

I am changing QListWidgetItem caption(QListWidgetItem text) by clicking a button on ui and under this i am also calling repaint() & update(), but the caption are not changing (refreshing) until we dose click on QlistWidget Area. plz help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

in the source I found this:

```
void QAbstractItemView::update(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    Q_D(QAbstractItemView);
    if (index.isValid()) {
        const QRect rect = visualRect(index);
        //this test is important for peformance reason
        //For example in dataChanged we simply update all the cells without checking
        //it can be a major bottleneck to update rects that aren't even part of the viewport
        if (d->viewport->rect().intersects(rect))
            d->viewport->update(rect);
    }
}
```

So, without a valid index, nothing will happen.

However, what seems to work (at least for me) is:

```
viewport()->update();
```

which also makes sense since this is called by QT (with a rect to be more performant, but it is optional).

Comment: I'm using QListView with custom deleagte and `viewport()->update();` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Might sound abusive, but give the list widget focus, this will force a repaint. Works without calling repaint() or update().

```
QWidget::setFocus()
```

Comment: My conscience does not allow me upvote this ugly hack, but I want to say thank you: it works!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be tied to the long standing bug in Qt, (cant find the number) where the `dataChanged` signal, does NOT trigger a repaint, if the ONLY thing that has changed in the icon.  It doesn't check `Qt::DecorationRole` to see if it has changed.

If you are making the change from the "view" you can force an update...
but if there are multiple views, it won't change the others, only the current one.

My suggestion, which does work, and is much less costly then a model reset, and will update all views.

Wrap the `dataChanged` signal call, with `layoutAboutToBeChanged()` and `layoutChanged()` like this:

```
layoutAboutToBeChanged();
"call functionality that change the icon to be shown"
emit dataChanged( index, index ); // does nothing
layoutChanged(); // forces a repaint of visible data on all open views
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the static function [`QCoreApplication::processEvents()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) to force a repaint.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still my problem is remain same, actually i am using my own delegate for QListWidget. is there any other way..

Comment: Hard to tell without any code. You might try calling `QListWidget::viewport()->update()` prior to calling processEvents